# DNS CNAMEs -- Is the client actually redirected or not?

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, ssl, cname-record

I believe this is a simple question, I thank you in advance for clearing it up for me.

Using this example:

```
foo.domain.com        CNAME  bar.example.com
bar.example.com        A      192.168.1.19
```

The client requests foo.domain.com in their browser.

Does the name lookup simply resolve to 192.168.1.19 and their request is made to the server at that address with host header foo.domain.com?  Or are they actually redirected and their request is made with host header bar.example.com?

Do I need to configure the server to listen on the new host name (foo.domain.com), with a valid SSL cert for it, etc?  Or is the existing configuration for bar.example.com sufficient?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DNS request is resolved first and then the browser connects to 192.168.1.19 with the following header:

```
Host: foo.domain.com
```

So yes, you have to configure a virtual host for *foo.domain.com*. Also, you will need a SSL certificate for *foo.domain.com*, because I suppose that you current SSL certificate is for *bar.example.com*.

Answer (score 3):

Because hosts are in  different zones, don't forget trailing dot after  hostname in CNAME

foo.domain.com        CNAME  bar.example.com.

> Does the name lookup simply resolve to 192.168.1.19 and their request is made to the server at that address with host header foo.domain.com?

Yes, exactly

> Do I need to configure the server to listen on the new host name (foo.domain.com), with a valid SSL cert for it, etc?

Yes, at least it's true for Apache (newer used IIS). Don't forget - you can't use **different certs** for **different hosts** on the **same IP**  and the **same port**. Your have to use wilcard cert of differentiate https ports per site